# How to implement Replay Event in Axon?

Tags: cqrs, axon

I have Two independent Spring-Boot Micro-Service one is Command side Another is Query Side Where Command Service Store events in Mongodb and put  Events  in RabbitMQ then  Query Side will Subscribe Queue and Build Query Modal.Now How To achieve Replay event And build Query modal in Axon?? is it possible where both service running independent on different-different node.if not possible then what should i follow to achieve that.

Answer (score 3):

If you choose to use RabbitMQ to distribute events you have to use Axon `Subscribing Event Processors` with `SubscribableMessageSource` as source - https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/extensions/spring-amqp#reading-events-from-an-amqp-queue

Only `Tracking Event Processor` supports replaying of events - https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/configuring-infrastructure-components/event-processing/event-processors#replaying-events

Consider using Axon Server or Kafka to distribute events. They support Tracking processors (and automatically Reply option as well).

You can find some examples here:

Axon Server: https://github.com/idugalic/digital-restaurant/blob/master/drestaurant-apps/drestaurant-microservices-rest-2/drestaurant-microservices-rest-2-query/src/main/kotlin/com/drestaurant/query/handler/RestaurantHandler.kt

Kafka: https://github.com/idugalic/digital-restaurant/blob/master/drestaurant-apps/drestaurant-microservices/drestaurant-microservices-query/src/main/kotlin/com/drestaurant/query/handler/RestaurantEventHandler.kt

...and yes, your Command side can be deployed independently of your Query side (projection). Query side can be re-created from scratch by replying all the events from the past. This will enable blue-green deployments (with projection DB schemas changing).

Best,
Ivan

Comment: Hi thanks. for information as i have gone  through the link ..that means with my current setup i can't do replay event  with rabbitMq or using Subscribing Event Processors i need to choose kafka or Axon Server for replaying event so i can use Tracking Event Processor! is it right??

Comment: If you want to `distribute` your events from the command side application (first JVM) to the query side application (second JVM) you have to choose Kafka or *Axon Server* in order to use Tracking Event Processors and benefit from Reply options that it will enable. Rabbit is not an option in your case.

Comment: FYI, the links in your answer don't work any more. I believe this is the updated version of your "replaying events" link: https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/events/event-processors/streaming#replaying-events